# scrapy yield logic broken

Tags: python, scrapy, yield

Having trouble with the following simple code which scrapes a vBulletin forum site:

```
class ForumSpider(CrawlSpider):
    ...

    rules = (
            Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths="//div[@class='threadlink condensed']"),
            callback='parse_threads'),
            )

    def parse_threads(self, response):

        thread = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        # get the list of posts
        posts = thread.select("//div[@id='posts']//table[contains(@id,'post')]/*")

        # plist = []
        for p in posts:
            table = ThreadItem()

            table['thread_id'] = (p.select("//input[@name='searchthreadid']/@value").extract())[0].strip()

            string_id = p.select("../@id").extract() # returns a list
            p_id = string_id[0].split("post")
            table['post_id'] = p_id[1]

            # plist.append(table)
            # return plist
            yield table
```

Some xpath hackiness aside, when I run this with **yield** I get really strange results with multiple hits for the same thread_id and post_id. Something like:

```
114763,1314728
114763,1314728
114763,1314728
114763,1314740
114763,1314740
114763,1314740
```

When I switch back to the same logic with **return** (in the comments) everything works fine. I think it might be some basic mistake with the generator, but I cannot figure it out. Why are the same posts being hit multiple times? Why does the code work using **return** but not **yield**?

The full code snippet in a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/denten/d898a48bcf2a496c7c07).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is an indentation problem. The following should work the same way as using list and return:

```
def parse_threads(self, response):

    thread = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    # get the list of posts
    posts = thread.select("//div[@id='posts']//table[contains(@id,'post')]/*")

    for p in posts:
        table = ThreadItem()

        table['thread_id'] = (p.select("//input[@name='searchthreadid']/@value").extract())[0].strip()

        string_id = p.select("../@id").extract() # returns a list
        p_id = string_id[0].split("post")
        table['post_id'] = p_id[1]

        yield table
```

UPD: I've fixed and improved the code of your `parse_threads` method, should work now:

```
def parse_threads(self, response):
    thread = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    thread_id = thread.select("//input[@name='searchthreadid']/@value").extract()[0].strip()
    post_id = thread.select("//div[@id='posts']//table[contains(@id,'post')]/@id").extract()[0].split("post")[1]

    # get the list of posts
    posts = thread.select("//div[@id='posts']//table[contains(@id,'post')]/tr[2]")
    for p in posts:
        # getting user_name
        user_name = p.select(".//a[@class='bigusername']/text()").extract()[0].strip()

        # skip adverts
        if 'Advertisement' in user_name:
            continue

        table = ThreadItem()
        table['user_name'] = user_name
        table['thread_id'] = thread_id
        table['post_id'] = p.select("../@id").extract()[0].split("post")[1]

        yield table
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah, my apologies! The indentation is correct in the running code. That was just copy and paste error.

Comment: Well, then it should work..don't see any mistakes. Could you please show the whole code of your spider, so I can reproduce it?

Comment: Let me know if you need items.py too. It is very simple now, as you can see. I've spent the whole day on this yesterday--really at my wit's end with the yield thing.

Comment: Now that I am looking at it--it might be the continue statement in the generator function.

Comment: Tested without the continue--same problem. 10 unique ids with return /  111 duplicate items with yield.

Comment: @denten I've updated the answer, please check. Btw, don't forget to accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: Still getting the duplicate hits!

Comment: Are you sure you it's wrong? Users can post several times in the thread. That's ok.

Comment: The post_ids are unique though, those should never duplicate, right?

Comment: I think the post_id needs to be inside the for loop. Trying that.

Comment: Yeah, should be inside the loop. I've edited the answer, please check.

Comment: Sorry, that still returns duplicates. The code I pasted in the gist returns no duplicates, but with yield the same post gets hit multiple times. Any ideas?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35045/discussion-between-denten-and-alecxe)